# How to use String.replace() to replace ALL occurrences of a pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser

In many divs I have to change the class name by replacing spaces with periods....

So I tried this

```
$(jqueryElements).each(function(index)
{ 
    jqueryElements[index].className.replace(' ','.');
});
```

When the class has two words it works fine... But when the class name has 3 or more words it fails....

```
className='one word';
jqueryElement[index].className.replace(' ','.'); // console-> one.word
className='many many words';
jqueryElement[index].className.replace(' ','.'); // console-> many.many words
```

There is something wrong??

I'm using Chrome 25, Win7, jQuery 1.8

EDIT 2

I need to replace spaces to search all the span elements that have a particular class name.

So I use jquery in this way...

```
$('#span-container').find('span.'+jqueryElements[index].className.replace(' ','.').text('there are '+span_counter+'spans with this classname');
```

The result of this request shoud be:

```
 $('#span-container').find('span.many.many.words).text('there are '+span_counter+'spans with this classname');
```

Instead I have:

```
$('#span-container').find('span.many.many words).text('there are '+span_counter+'spans with this classname');
```

Comment: err, why are you doing this?  spaces separate class names; combining them doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use replace, use `split` and `join`:

```
jqueryElements[index].className.split(' ').join('.');
```

Comment: i agree with this... in this http://jsperf.com/split-vs-replace test case the split().join() function has the best performance in all browsers  thank you for the answer

Comment: i make a new test case, see the http://jsperf.com/split-vs-replace/2 and give me an opinion of this... thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use `.replace(/ /g, '.')` instead.  The `g` means global (as in "global replace"). I am a bit skiptical about what you're trying to do though.

Comment: global means all chars??? including '-' or  '_'?? because i want to replace only spaces, white spaces...

Comment: Global means "_perform this substitution multiple times on each piece of input_".

Comment: great! this works fine! thank you, im not sure if i have to erase the question... because is simple question, but in all tutorials the answer is ".replace(' ','.'), this is a different aproach...

Comment: No need to remove the question.  I recommend doing some reading on JavaScript regex, though.  Here's [a good place to start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: i make a new test case, see the jsperf.com/split-vs-replace/2 and give me an opinion of this... thank you –